# Firefox crashing on Kubuntu (Linux Ubuntu) Half a dozen times a day on closing application

Tags: linux, firefox, crash, kubuntu

My firefox application crashes on closing half a dozen times a day.

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04.2 (Linux)

Firefox 39.0

I tried changing Firefox settings to suppress the reports but to no avail.

Hope someone can offer advice or help me to troubleshoot this since I have been unsuccessful using my own resources and limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem, due to add-on and plugin incompatibility - crash only on closing Firefox - happened in my Windows installation. To confirm it's an extension issue, [restart in Safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode).

If that solves the problem, then enable *half* your extensions, to see which half the troublemaker is in. Then in that half, enable only half of those left (i.e. one quarter of the total). *usw.* This binary search found the culprit (a download manager that needed updating) quickly for me.